# Netbeans project skeleton

Tags: php, netbeans

Is there a plugin for netbeans that will help you create a skeleton project so everytime you are starting a new project you could simply click File -> New Project from Skeleton instead of copying files manually? Or does anyone have any idea on how to do that?

Cheers

Comment: I would suggest creating shell script to do all copying for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link to an blog describing how to do this:

[Hack Your Own Custom NetBeans Project Templates](http://netbeans.dzone.com/tips/hack-your-own-custom-project-t)